# Make single widget area top level in 4.0 Customize Panel

Tags: widgets, theme-customizer

So I have a widget area that, in v4.0, is burried in a dropdown within the secondary Widgets panel on the Customize panel page.

Because it's the only widget area it feels rather silly being burried so deeply, so I'm wondering if there's a way to override the nesting and make that widget area dropdown a top-level section like it was in v3.x?

It looks like this was brought up by the Core team [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27406#comment:62), but didn't gain any traction.

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

Admittedly, this feels hacky but seems to do the job just fine.

In my existing `customize_register` hook I set the following:

```
// Retreive the widget section in the Theme Customizer
// We need to cast the return of get_section to an object
// "the_widgets_section" in get_section is the ID of the registered widget area
$widget_area = (object) $wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-the_widgets_section' )
// The value of panel will be 'widgets', so we set it back to '' (top level panel)
$widget_area->panel = '';
// If you're so inclined, we can change the title of it as well.
$widget_area->title = __( 'My Widgets', 'textdomain' );
```